# Shell script that finds a word within a file selected by a user

Tags: linux, bash, shell, grep

I am training to do shell scripting as a hobby, I was stumbled on a task I was given by my tutor.

The task is to make a shell script that you can enter a file name you want to search in and then it will respond if it exists or not; then if it exists you have another option to find a certain word in the file that exist in there the certain word must be shown.

Here is what I've done so far. My tutor only gave me a hint it has something to do with grep??

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "search the word you want to find"
  
read strfile

echo "Enter the file you wish to search in"
grep $strfile 

"strword" strfile
```

Here's the start of my improved work.

```
#!/bin/bash

printf "Enter a filename:
"
read str
 if [[ -f "$str" ]]; then

echo "The file '$str' exists."

else

echo "The file '$str' does not exists"
```

It seems the file isnt then asking for the word I want to find after searching for a file name.

What am I doing wrong?

## !/bin/bash

read -p "enter a filename:" filename

if [[ -f $ filename ]] ;

echo " the filename exists " then

read -p "enter the word you want to find. : word

[grep -c  $word $filename

else echo "the file $str doesn't exist."
fi

Comment: `man grep` gives "grep [OPTIONS] PATTERN [FILE...]". man is a nifty thing.

Comment: Break this into pieces. To start with, can you solve the first part? "The task is to make a shell script that you can enter a file name ... and then it will respond if it exists or not." Get that working first, then you can move on to the next part.

Comment: My tutor did say to use the web for guidance rather than working it out on my own.

Comment: Glad that you've dare to tell the truth. Some of them gets their assignment solved without telling so!

Answer (score 4):

One solution:

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p "Enter a filename: " filename

if [[ -f $filename ]] ; then
    echo "The file $filename exists."
    read -p "Enter the word you want to find: " word
    grep "$word" "$filename"
else
    echo "The file $filename does not exist."
fi
```

Quite a few variants possible.

Comment: Nice; please replace `$filename` with `"$filename"` in the `grep` command to guard against filenames that need quoting (e.g., embedded spaces); also, references to `$str` should be to `$filename`.

Comment: The shell script is only answering one half of the script, how can I make it to find the word after finding the existing file?

Comment: Can you rephrase? I am not sure I understand. The script will display the line in which the word appears in the file (the `grep`command). To print only the word, use the `-o` option. To print the line number, use the `-n` option, to count the occurence use the `-c`option.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the word counting part by:

```
exists=$(grep -c $word $file)
if [[ $exists -gt 0 ]]; then
    echo "Word found"
fi
```

That's what you're missing, the rest of your script is ok.

"grep -c" counts lines which contain $word, so a file:

```
word word other word
word
nothing
```

will produce value "2". Putting grep in $() let's you store the result in a variable. I think the rest is self-explanatory, especially, that you already have it in you post :)

Comment: backticks are deprecated in 2013. Thanks to use `$( )` form instead. And if using bash, use `[[ ]]` tests, not `[ ]`

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about it.

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
 # cat find.sh
 #!/bin/bash
 echo -e "Enter the file name:"
 read fi
 echo -e "Enter the full path:"
 read pa
 se=$(find "$pa" -type f -name "$fi")
 co=$(cat $se | wc -l)
 if [ $co -eq 0 ]
 then
 echo "File not found on current path"
 else
 echo "Total file found: $co"
 echo "File(s) List:"
 echo "$se"
 echo -e "Enter the word which you want to search:"
 read wa
 sea=$(grep -rHn "$wa" $se)
 if [ $? -ne 0 ]
 then
 echo "Word not found"
 else
 echo "File:Line:Word"
 echo "$sea"
 fi
 fi
```

output:

```
 # ./find.sh
 Enter the file name:
 best
 Enter the full path:
 .
 Total file(s) found: 1
 File(s) List:
 ./best
 Enter the word which you want to search:
 root
 File:Line:Word
 ./best:1:root
 # ./find.sh
 Enter the file name:
 besst
 Enter the full path:
 .
 File not found on current path
```

Comment: Wouldn't that leave rubbish ".se" and ".sea" files?

Comment: These files will be on the path as "hidden files" so there will be no issues.

Comment: There is no such thing as "hidden" files on Linux. Files beginning with '.' are just ignored by regular expressions beginning with an asterisk. And what is the point of keeping them anyway? Can't you put the value in a variable, or at least delete them after you're done?

Comment: rm -rf .se .sea add in script to remove those files.

Comment: Sorry for the delay darth, script has modified

Answer (score 0):

```bash
#!/bin/bash

read -p "Enter a filename: " filename

if [ -f $filename ]
then
    echo "The file $filename exists."
    read -p "Enter the word you want to find: " word
    result=`grep -o -m 1 "$word" $filename` 
    if [ -z "$result" ];
    then
        echo "Entered word ('$word') was not found.";
    else
        echo "Entered word ('$word') is present in '$filename'."
    fi
else
    echo "The file $filename does not exist."
fi
```

Here's an example of the script being run:

```shell
# file and word found
$ bash findword.sh
Enter a filename: fib.py
The file fib.py exists.
Enter the word you want to find: fib
Entered word ('fib') is present in 'fib.py'.

# file not found
$ bash findword.sh
Enter a filename: bib.py
The file bib.py does not exist.

# word not found
$ bash findword.sh
Enter a filename: fib.py
The file fib.py exists.
Enter the word you want to find: bib
Entered word ('bib') was not found.
```