# Errors on a shell script that tries to find a word inside a filename

Tags: linux, bash, shell, grep

Here's my issue I've been working on this shell script for a while now and I don't know what I'm doing wrong. The shell script gives errors such as, `grep:textfile1.txt no such file or directory` and `line 10 syntax error 'else'`. I'm not sure what syntaxes go where. Here's my script.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Find The file you want to search the word in"
read filename
cd ~ $filename
echo "enter the word you want to find"
read word1
grep -F "$word1" "$filename"
if $word exists in $filename then
        echo "$word exist in $filename"
else
        echo "the file or word doesn't exist!"
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19795643/shell-script-that-finds-a-word-within-a-file-selected-by-a-user/19796377#19796377 Same homework?

Comment: There are so many things wrong in your script a single SO question isn't going to cut it. Please show some effort in isolating faulty behaviors to two or three line independent script snippets, and asking a question per part you all don't understand.

Comment: @damienfrancois same user...

Comment: Write your script in chunks and test them as you go until you are experienced enough not to.  You basically have this... `read -p "enter file and word to search separated by a space" FILENAME WORD; grep -q $WORD $FILENAME && echo found || echo not found`

Answer (score 2):

There are too many errors in your script:

> cd ~ $filename

The `$filename` is pointless, the shell will simply ignore it, and it will change the working directory to your home directory. Also keep in mind that changing to your home directory will affect the behavior of the program later when you run `grep` on the specified filename, because relative paths will have to be relative to your home directory to work, otherwise the file may not be found.

> grep -F "$word1" "$filename"

You run `grep` but you don't evaluate its result.

> if $word exists in $filename then

There is no "exists" operator in bash.
And, you must put a semicolon before `then`, or put it on a new line.

Finally, you didn't put the closing `fi` for the `if` statement.

I think you meant something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Find The file you want to search the word in"
read filename
cd
echo "enter the word you want to find"
read word1
if grep -qF "$word1" "$filename" 2>/dev/null; then
    echo "$word1 exists in $filename"
else
    echo "the file or word doesn't exist!"
fi
```

Comment: The `cd` seems kind of misplaced in the first place, since this basically requires you to write a full path if you want to search a file which is not in your home directory.

Comment: @tripleee yeah, it's really strange. I added more explanation to highlight that fact and to question the real intention there.